# How to type `PyObject* const*` in Cython

Tags: python, cython, python-extensions

Let's take this as an example: [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c._PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords)

The definition of the type `_PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords` is:

```
PyObject *_PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords(PyObject *self,
                                       PyObject *const *args,
                                       Py_ssize_t nargs,
                                       PyObject *kwnames);
```

How do I type `PyObject *const *` in Cython?

Doing this does not work:

```
ctypedef PyObject *(*_PyCFunctionFastWithKeywords)(PyObject *, PyObject *const *, Py_ssize_t, PyObject *)
```

Comment: What if you do `from cpython.ref cimport PyObject` first?

Comment: Yeah, I did that.